# Php Using Fopen function with live streaming(rtp)

Tags: php, vlc, rtp

I am trying to prepare a webcam streaming page. I created a **vlc** streaming and here is what I wrote in the command line to run my webcam.

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,acodec=none}:rtp{dst=239.0.0.1,port=5004,mux=ts}'
```

After typing this code i can see my webcam by typing

```
rtp://239.0.0.1:5004/
```

to the browser. Its okay up to here.

I prepared a php streaming file and it opens static video files with

```
fopen('localhost/sample.mp4','rb')
```

command and it works properly. But when I pass "rtp://239.0.0.1:5004"/ in

```
 fopen( 'rtp://239.0.0.1:5004/', "rb" )
```

command, I get en error 502 gateway that probably means it has not opened rtp file.

What should I do ? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that comes after the `fopen` line?

Comment: `fopen` doesn't support `RTP`, see [PHP Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/transports.php). You need sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can only open resources using some protocols:

| Protocol | Description |
| --- | --- |
| file:// | Accessing local filesystem |
| http:// | Accessing HTTP(s) URLs |
| ftp:// | Accessing FTP(s) URLs |
| php:// | Accessing various I/O streams |
| zlib:// | Compression Streams |
| data:// | Data (RFC 2397) |
| glob:// | Find pathnames matching pattern |
| phar:// | PHP Archive |
| ssh2:// | Secure Shell 2 |
| rar:// | RAR |
| ogg:// | Audio streams |
| expect:// | Process Interaction Streams |

As you see **rtp** is not one of these. You need to find/write rtp wrapper to read this resource.